# create an instance for each element of an array ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to create an instance of a class that each includes an element from the class's array. The array is like this

```
class CorporatePanel < ActiveRecord::Base


  TEXT_ONLY = 'text only'
  IMAGE_LEFT = 'image left'
  IMAGE_RIGHT = 'image right'
  IMAGE_ONLY = 'image only'
  VIDEO = 'video'
  PANEL_TYPE = [TEXT_ONLY, IMAGE_LEFT, IMAGE_RIGHT, IMAGE_ONLY, VIDEO]
```

So for each panel type i want an instance of the class corporate panel.

```
@corp_page = CorporatePage.create!(title: 'Home', static_descriptor: 'Home', workflow_state: 'draft')
    @corp_panel = CorporatePanel::PANEL_TYPE
    if @corp_page.title == 'Home'
      puts "PAGE CREATED"
      (@corp_panel.count).times do 
        corp_panel = CorporatePanel.new
        @corp_panel.each do |x|
          corp_panel.panel_type = x 
        end
        if corp_panel.save
          puts "#{corp_panel.title} created"
        else
          puts "#{corp_panel.title} not created"
          puts corp_panel.errors.inspect
        end
      end
    else
      puts "Corp Page not saved"
      puts @corp_page.inspect
    end
```

So on every iteration through corporate panel it uses a different panel type. At the moment it creates five of each panel!

Thanks in Advance folks

Comment: Why are you calling `(@corp_panel.count).times do`? this does the same thing 5 times (as many panels as you have in `@corp_panel`

Comment: Yeah but if it grows then I want it to be able do it without changing it

Comment: sorry, I don't follow - what grows? what changes?

Comment: If the array changes in size, then the rake file doesnt need to change right?

Comment: @UriAgassi if I am missing something (which is likely) could you tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the array documentation i found the method 'pop', to remove the last element of every array, seeing as this constant is an array, it worked.

```
corp_panel.panel_type = CorporatePanel::PANEL_TYPE.pop
```